# how to make cmp to see the different of two dictionary?

Tags: python

how can i fix my code? i am trying to find the difference(Counter)of two different dictionaries 
its calculating the space too

```
def compute_word_importance(fpath1,fpath2):


    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    with open(fpath1, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        for line1 in f:
            for word in line1.split(" ",maxsplit=6):
                list1.append(word)
    with open(fpath2, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as x:
        for line2 in x:
            for word in line2.split(" ",maxsplit=6):
                list2.append(word)


    if list1==0 and list2==0:
        return None
    else:

            c = collections.Counter(list1)
            c.subtract(list2)
    return c


ERROR: The returned Counter is not correct:
... Observed: Counter({'tljdlkr': -1, 'ngaegwgsyxvkjctmpy': -1, 'xf\n': -1, 'dmarh': -1, 'wjca\n': -1, 'kyykvjx\n': -1, 'i\n': -1, 'kpwnkpzjsscqin': -1, 'jkpmvfbf\n': -1, 'dj': -1, 'doljkqq': -1, 'kjtbgcjn': -1, '\n': -2})
... Expected: Counter({'tljdlkr': -1, 'doljkqq': -1, 'jkpmvfbf': -1, 'dmarh': -1, 'xf': -1, 'i': -1, 'kpwnkpzjsscqin': -1, 'kjtbgcjn': -1, 'dj': -1, 'ngaegwgsyxvkjctmpy': -1, 'wjca': -1, 'kyykvjx': -1})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about the late answer. I just implement the function like this.

Let me give a brief explain. First, we must read ALL words in two file. After that, we will count the occurrences of each word in file1 and the file 2. That is a simply mission. Finally we return a list.

```
 def compute_word_importance(fpath1,fpath2):
    l = set()
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    with open(fpath1, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        for line1 in f:
            for word in line1.split(" "):
                list1.append(word)
    with open(fpath2, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as x:            
        for line2 in x:
            for word in line2.split(" "):
                list2.append(word)

    for word in list1:
        t = list1.count(word) - list2.count(word)                
        l.add((word,t))

    for word in list2:
        t = list1.count(word) - list2.count(word)
        l.add((word,t))

    return list(l)
```

Resutlt for example:

```
print(compute_word_importance("Text1.txt", "Text2.txt"))

[('This', 0), ('programming', 1), ('Python', 1), ('about', 0), ('is', 0), ('Spam.', -1), ('text', 0), ('language.', 1)]
```

EDIT: From your original question, I make it simpler.

```
def compute_word_importance(fpath1,fpath2):    
    list1 = []
    list2 = []
    with open(fpath1, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
        for line1 in f:
            for word in line1.split(" "):
                list1.append(word)
    with open(fpath2, 'rt', encoding='UTF-8') as x:            
        for line2 in x:
            for word in line2.split(" "):
                list2.append(word)

    c1 = collections.Counter(list1)
    c2 = collections.Counter(list2)

    return (c1-c2)
```

And the result of this

```
Counter({'language.': 1, 'programming': 1, 'Python': 1})
```

Comment: no i am trying to make it the  opposite way and calculate the  dictionaries .....0 if both dictionaries are equal, -1 if dict1 < dict2 and 1 if dict1 > dic2.

Comment: What does it mean dict1<dict2?

Comment: suppose text1.txt =This text is about Python programming language.     text2.txt= This text is about Spam.

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention it there

Comment: i only understood the > and if both are equal but i couldn't make them  @gavd

Comment: sorry for the misunderstanding but could you help me please @gavd

Comment: OK, but can you just clarify this? What is your order? Is it alphabetic, for example, "abcd"<"def"? Or is it the length of words, for example, "abcd">"def"?

Comment: i added all of the question from by book above , i think its not asking for the length but the occurance of the words in the two dictionaries

Comment: thanks you really helped now its working well but its missing the -1 and 0 and return an empty counter

Comment: sorry just now i saw your updated function but when i check it in an automatic evaluation it says ERROR: "compute_word_importance()" shall produce a <class 'collections.Counter'>, but produced a value with type <class 'list'>.

Comment: Let try again. I compile it well. :)

Comment: yes exactly but the automatic evaluation is expecting collections.counter in the result same as the last one not in the list... the last one failed to return -1 and none only

Comment: i edited my code with yours now its working well but how can i return None when the dictionaries are empty? can you fix it pls @gavd

Comment: Just check the dictionaries is empty before comparing. For example, if (not bool(dict)) return None

Comment: i did it i got an error its calculating the space after the sentence please check my code

Comment: here is the error '\n': -2 its not supposed to be there